# MacOS gcc dylib and clang app - exception handling issue

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang

For a **legacy project** I have to compile our code into a **dylib** with **gcc** which is then linked into a **clang** app starting with Intel-based macOS 10.15 (Catalina). I work with Big Sur 11.4 on a Mac Mini 2020 M1.
For testing purposes, I have created a small C++ project with header
*foo.h*

```
#pragma once
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo();
   virtual ~Foo();

   void throw_runtime_error(const char* msg);
   int bar(int a);
};
```

and code *foo.cpp*

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdexcept>
#include "foo.h"
using namespace std;

Foo::Foo()
{
  cout << "Foo:Foo() called" << endl;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
  cout << "Foo:~Foo() called" << endl;
}

void Foo::throw_runtime_error(const char* msg)
{
  cout << "throwing runtime_error " << msg << endl;
  throw runtime_error( msg );
}

int Foo::bar(int a)
{
  cout << "Foo::bar(" << a << ") called" << endl;
  return a + 1;
}
```

To create the dylib in a *build* subdir, I use the homebrewn *g++ 10.2* with
`g++-10 -arch x86_64 -fexceptions -dynamiclib -I../include ../src/foo.cpp -o ../bin/libMyDylib.dylib`

For testing, how to be used along with *clang 12.2.0* I have created a *main.cpp* in the *bin* subdir

```
#include "../include/foo.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  try
  {
    foo.throw_runtime_error("Hello you ugly little creatures!");
  }
  catch( const std::runtime_error &r )
  {
    std::cout << "Caught foo runtime_error, what = " << r.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch( const std::exception &x )
  {
    std::cout << "Caught foo exception, what = " << x.what() << std::endl;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout << "Caught foo exception, but without what()" << std::endl;
  }
  return foo.bar(42);
}
```

Now, if I use *gcc-10* to compile *main.cpp* and link it with *libMyDylib.dylib* via `g++-10 -arch x86_64 -L/Users/macos/bin  -lMyDylib main.cpp -o main` the exception handler in *main.cpp* catches the *std::runtime_error* properly.

If I use *clang 12.2* along with `g++ -arch x86_64 -L/Users/macos/bin -lMyDylib main.cpp -o main`

then the output shows that only the `catch (...)` handler is triggered.

```
./main
Foo:Foo() called
throwing runtime_error Hello you ugly little creatures!
Caught foo exception, but without what()
Foo::bar(42) called
Foo:~Foo() called
```

**So, can someone please give me a hint, what I am missing, in order to get 'cross-compiler' exceptions properly handled?**

Thnxalot

Comment: not sure you can, gcc will be using libstdc++ and clang will be using libc++ so the `std::exception` thrown by your gcc code will not be the same type as the `std::exception` that your clang code is trying to catch. You might be able to throw and catch your own exception type (not derived from `std::exception`) but ultimately c++ interop across shared library boundaries is tricky, adding in compiling with different compilers and standard libraries will not make it easier

Comment: I have now tried it with a self-tinkered Exception like 

`class MyException
{
public:
MyException()
{
msg[0]='O';msg[1]='k';msg[2]='\0';
}
virtual ~MyException(){}
const char* const what(){return msg;}
private:
  char msg[32];
};`

but this exception is also not caught properly (just the ... handler). Not clear, what's going wrong..

Comment: you'll need to make sure `MyException` is exported from the library and used in the executable so that they're the same type not different types with the same name, even then you'll be at the mercy of the exception handling and RTTI of both compilers being compatible